# Convert Doyxgen xml output to DITA

Tags: doxygen, dita

Is there a way to take in doxygen output and convert it to dita files, which can then be rendered by e.g. Oxygen XML Author?

Comment: Can you use the doxygen xml output for this? or is there more required for this?

Comment: @albert That's what I want to know. Is there already prior work done to smoothen this combination? Is there built-in support from either tool to support this? Is there an existing plugin/script? I can't find any solid mention of support from either tool, nor 3rd party work.

Comment: Doxygen exports xml but not according to the DITA schema. In doxygen buglist there is the issue: Bug 654087 - Doxygen support for DITA output (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654087) but I don't know the status (but doesn't look active / reachable).

Comment: I just did a quick google search (doxygen DITA) and got some hists (didn't research them e.g. https://github.com/dita-community/doxygen2dita, https://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/mailman/message/27767439/)

Comment: @albert The doxygen2dita plugin looks promising. Thanks. I will look into it.

Comment: Please report back with your experience / problems.